# Which factors have been most prominent in the switching of codes amongst professional players?

Tags: rugby-union, rugby, rugby-league

It is not uncommon for professional sportsmen to [switch from one football code to another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_players_who_have_converted_from_one_football_code_to_another).

Specifically considering the move from Rugby League to Rugby Union and vice-versa, what have been the most prominent factors in athletes making this switch?

I can speculate that the financial benefits may be one of the key motivators but I'd like to learn of any hard statistics or research into this matter.

Comment: I will have a think about this one.  When Union was amateur, money was clearly a motivation - now that particular drive is more in the other direction as Union is the more wealthy of the two Rugby codes.

Answer (score 2):

Receiving big money contracts is certainly one of the benefits of switching codes. In the last ten years or so, players switching between codes have received multi-million dollar contracts for doing so, and before even playing a professional game in their "new" sport.

Most players though that have switched in recent years have reached the pinnacle of their player careers at a young age. For example, [Karmichael Hunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmichael_Hunt) and [Israel Folau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Folau) both have won NRL premierships, various awards, and represented their state and country at the highest level. A change to codes that feature very similar skill sets, whether to rugby union or AFL, would bring about a new set of challengers for these elite sportsmen.